# Overriding implicit setter method with a trait in Scala

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, traits

I'm trying to implement a stackable trait pattern in Scala (similar to http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html). Here's my attempt. I start defining a simple class:

```
class Topping(var name:String)
```

That class declaration should automatically create a getter and a setter method for variable called "name". So then I create a trait extending this class:

```
trait LoggingNameTrait extends Topping {

  override def name_=(aName:String) {
    print(aName)
    super.name_=(aName) // this line doesn't compile
  }

}
```

If the code above worked, it should override the implicit setter for the "name" field, printing it on the console and then calling the setter of the class which uses the trait. I get a "super may not be used on variable name".

Do you know why the Scala compiler doesn't let me override the implicit setter?

Comment: `super.name_=(aName) // this line doesn't compile` how about a simple `super.name=aName` ? why is name_ abstract by the way?

Comment: That doesn't work. And yes, I should remove the abstract modifier there. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's an implementation restriction: `super` only works for `def`s.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1938

Comment: Interesting. But I'm actually trying to overwrite a setter (I know it's a setter for a var, but the implicit setter is a def, right?), so I'd think it should work. That issue says "traits should be able to call super on fields", but I'm calling the setter from the trait, is that considered to be a field access as well, right?

Comment: Add your use-case in the comments of that bug. You're hitting the same limitation, even though it's a from a different angle.

Answer (score 2):

The setter isn't called `name_`, it's called `name_=` (note the equals sign).

Comment: I just tried:
`abstract override def name_=(aName:String) {
    print(aName)
    super.name_=(aName)
  }`
And it's still not working... :(

Comment: While this answer is factually correct, it does not apply to question asked. The answer by nonVirtualThunk is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that though scala in some sense creates the `name_=` method automatically when you declare the variable, it is not available for overriding and the like unless you declare it explicitly. The following, however, should work:

```
class Topping(var _name:String) {
    def name : String = _name
    def name_= (s : String) { _name = s }
}

trait LoggingNameTrait extends Topping {

  abstract override def name_=(aName:String) {
    print(aName)
    super.name_=(aName) // this line doesn't compile   }

}
```

This should be functionally equivalent to what you were trying initially,

```
val t = new Topping with LoggingNameTrait
t.name = "Name"
```

Will print out "Name" and set the internal `_name` value, such that `val s = t.name` will assign "Name" to `s`, as you would expect. The only difference is the more explicit definition of the setter and getter functions.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that, and it worked just fine. But I don't want to declare the getter and setter methods, I want to override the implicit ones! Is there a reason why this doesn't work in Scala?